# Selenium-Webdriver for chrome/chromium has problems with running two profiles at once?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I've recently run into a fairly large issue with selenium-webdriver (for Node.js) - everything works just fine, but only until you try to run two profiles at the same time!

Normally I specify the argument `user-data-dir` with a value of the user data directory, usually `${os.homedir()}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data` (in case of Windows at least).
On top of that of course, I also define the `profile-directory` argument, with a value of for example `Default`, or `Profile 1`, etc.

The problem arises when I try to open two profile directories at the same time in separate chromium windows, it does actually launch two (or more) chrome/chromium instances, however only the first one that was opened actually continues to run the rest of the Node.js script instructions.

Answer (score 0):

After pondering this question for a while, I have figured out that the problem arises when the `user-data-dir` of multiple profiles is shared, the solution to this problem is therefore to only use multiple profiles at once if their parent directory is **not** the same directory.

In short: The solution is to have a different parent directory for each profile